# SSL Exception on Glassfish when load increases

Tags: java, exception, servlets, ssl, glassfish

When our Glassfish server is at the beginning of an increase in load we keep getting the following  expceptions.

com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352): peer not authentic.  After more than several they go away.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please format your question to be a **real** question. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: And when you post exceptions please paste them accurately. That is not what the exception actually says.

Answer (score 1):

'Peer not authenticated', which is what that exception *really* says, means that the client didn't send a certificate. This has nothing whatsoever to do with load, it has to do with the configuration at the client.